# Without using a pre-built physics engine, how can I implement 3D collision detection from scratch?

Tags: collision-detection, physics, architecture

I want to tackle some basic 3D collision detection and was wondering how engines handle this and give you a pretty interface and make it so easy... I want to do it all myself, however.

2D collision detection is extremely simple and can be done multiple ways that even beginner programmers could think up:

1. When the pixels touch;
2. when a rectangle range is exceeded;
3. when a pixel object is detected near another one in a pixel-based rendering engine.

But 3D is different with one dimension, but complex in many more so... **what are the general, basic understanding/examples on how 3D collision detection can be implemented?**

Think two shaded, OpenGL cubes that are moved next to each other with a simple OpenGL rendering context and keyboard events.

Comment: GameDev.SE isn't really the place to be told how a 3d collision system works on the inside. Maybe how to use a particular one for a particular task though.

Comment: Here's something I recently wrote about this. Please also see Dirk Gregorius's 2013 GDC lecture: http://www.randygaul.net/2014/05/22/deriving-obb-to-obb-intersection-sat/

Comment: @RandyGaul Doesn't help at all.

Comment: How does that not help in the case of "Think two shaded, OpenGL cubes that are moved next to each other with a simple OpenGL rendering context and keyboard events."?

Comment: @AndyHarglesis Sorry but this is how collision detection is implemented. Either you'll have to deal with online articles or buy Ericson's Orange Book.

Comment: Basically there are two main theorems, modified GJK and the Separating Axis Theorem. That's about it, and they don't even work for non-convex shapes.

Comment: That there are books dedicated to answering this question is pretty much exactly [how we define when a question is *too broad*](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). What's the most prominent narrower problem right now?

Comment: The problem with this question is that it assumes that the way to do collision in 2D is via pixels (options 1 & 3). In reality, pixel based collision is inaccurate to provide a more-than-basic physics engine in 2D, and moreover, extended to 3D, the equivalent would be to use 3D voxels. The more reasonable/accurate approach for handling collision in 2D is to use 
 the Separating Axis Theorem (examples here: http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html), and luckily, it extends to 3D quite easily.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those "It depends..." answers, be forewarned :)

The complexity of collision detection in 3D depends on the complexity of the bounding volume for solids.  By bounding volumes, I mean what shape you are wanting to consider for the collision calculations.  You might be drawing a really complicated spikey ball on the screen, but consider that treating it like a sphere might be just fine.

**The Really Easy Way**

Model everything with a sphere.  Then you just have to measure the distance between object centers, and if the distance between two objects is <= the radius of both, you know there's a collision.

You might consider this a poor way to do it, but if you really don't care about "perfect" collisions, then it might be just fine.  Do you really need perfect collisions?  Can you get by with a bit of fuzziness?  Then modelling as spheres is great.

**The More Challenging Way**

Ah if only life were just billiards games...   If you can't use spheres, you're going to have to start computing intersections between more complicated solids.  Which I'm guessing there are many resources for online.  And that I really don't understand it well enough to give a good answer.

You can still use spheres as a quick 'first pass' approach.  Give each solid a bounding sphere, and if you have no overlapping spheres, then you know there's no chance of a collision, so it's not worth bothering with more expensive calculations.

**An Incremental Development Approach**

You've expressed interest in doing this yourself, which is great - but also potentially a complicated undertaking.  To up your odds of completing it, I'd suggest doing the work in steps

First, start with a "minimum viable collision system" - start with the spheres method.  Get your environment working with sphere collisions.  Will it be perfect?  No.  But it will give you a good rough idea of how collision as a game element work.

Next, when you're happy with it (in the sense it works with spheres), then start adding complex collision detection.  That actually fits nicely with using collisions as a 'first pass' calculation in a complex environment.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use bounding-boxes.

Calculate an invisible box around each of your game objects. When two of these boxes intersect, you have a collision.

When you need more accuracy, you can make each object consist of multiple bounding boxes, so they approximate its geometry more closely. [This answer on Arquade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/what-is-a-hit-box) has screenshots of first person shooters with visible bounding-boxes.